# looks like CSS border is not applied to my paragraphs

Tags: html, css

For some reason, when I run the HTML, the CSS isn't executed, and I can't understand why? This happened yesterday, but somehow it solved itself. I'm new to this, so I'm trying to learn the basics. Thanks to anyone who helps!

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Border Color</title>
        <link href="/Users/leighton_blackburn/Documents/Border-Color.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="one"> Hello </p>
        <p class="two"> Hello </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
p.one {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #0088dd;}
p.two {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #bbbbaa #111111 #ee3e80 #0088dd;}
```

Comment: What is the address/location of the HTML file?

Comment: use relative links, not absolute.

Comment: /Users/leighton_blackburn/Documents/Border-Color.html The same location as the CSS.

Comment: I don't know what that means Nick. aha. Could you explain?

Comment: you added a `/` to your ending `<link>` tag. Get rid of it.

    <link href="/Users/leighton_blackburn/Documents/Border-Color.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >

Comment: Just tried that, but still no luck. Thanks though@

Comment: If both HTML document and CSS file are in the same folder, get rid of all the path, leave just the file name `Border-Color.css`. Also, bear in mind that the CSS you have there won't show anything different even when applied

Comment: What editor do you guys use to write html and css?

Comment: Open your browser's console, usually `<F12>` and see if it reports any 404 errors...

Comment: Open you browser's developer tools. Look in the Net tab. Look to see what URL is being requested. Look to see what the response is.

Comment: Cheers. Can I ask, why it won't?

Comment: Please, please, please let us not start an editor war.

Comment: Note, adding a `/` is totally valid and even good practice at the end of `link` elements.

Comment: Yes, those styles should affect a border but the border does not exist. Try removing them and applying something like `border: 1px solid red`

Comment: aha. Just give me a few decent examples. I don't really know many.

Comment: @LeightonBlackburn — You have no `border-style` and the default is `none`.

Comment: @Mukul215 Actually the self-closing, trailing `/` in elements that cannot have content imho is still best way to go, even though HTML 5 (sadly) dropped that being a requirement. It allows for XML-based (DTD or Schema) validation of your code.

Comment: @Quentin - I'll try it now.

Comment: @connexo — It has an HTML 5 Doctype. HTML 5 rules can't be expressed in DTDs or schemas.

Comment: can you give the structure of these two files - `.html` and `.css` also open the page in your browser and then click on view page source after that click on the link of your css, check if the source of the css file is shown or not? if not, then the directory might be wrong..

Comment: @RohitKumar, the OP already said both files are in the same folder

Comment: @Quentin Sure, but you can still check for well-formedness, which in many cases can be a problem for the validity of HTML 5 as well - and also massively for the rendering process. Try to not properly close a `div` in your page, or an anchor.

Comment: Or you could just use an HTML 5 aware validator and catch lots of other errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your link tag to this:

```
<link href="Border-Color.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Also, you are not declaring a border style in you CSS. Try this:

```
p.one {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #0088dd;
    border-style: solid;
}
p.two {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #bbbbaa #111111 #ee3e80 #0088dd;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

You could also write this shorthand as:

```
p.one {
    border: 2px solid #0088dd;
}
p.two {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #bbbbaa #111111 #ee3e80 #0088dd;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed to do!

Answer (score 0):

```
    p.one {
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #0088dd;}
    p.two {
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #bbbbaa #111111 #ee3e80 #0088dd;}
```

I do not feel the problem is your external css link. The problem is about how you declare your css.

Hope you get it.

Comment: Cheers! It finally worked. Needed to declare what type of border I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: That's what all others have explained the past 30 minutes. This is just a lame copy of those solutions.

Comment: It is not a lame solution. Because I told him the direct solution, and what 'was not' the problem. I was not suggesting him to try this, then this. Furthermore, I did not read comments. @connexo

Comment: "_Furthermore, I did not read comments_" - Franco, that's where you sinned. Comments and other anwers are to be read before answering/commenting. Also, @connexo didn't say it was a lame solution, he said it was a lame copy of other solution. You don't read comments and when you do, you don't read them carefully. You should try to improve this

Comment: You could not know that pathing was not part of the problem. You just "*felt it isn't*"... The others just made sure that the path is not an additional part of the problem - and they helped OP understand how to properly reference files so the project works when moved elsewhere.

Comment: Then just make StackOverFlow better, no answers and just comments.

Agreed? Oh wait.

StackOverflow says:
Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.


This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
http://stackoverflow.com/tour

So next time, feel free to comment.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @chiapa The copy of a solution it is a solution by default. Other thing is that I do not consider my solution as a copy. We got information by so many ways, books, e-books, etc. Are we copying their solutions?.Do  we need to show their references, don't you?

But you are right in sooooooome way... "Comments and other anwers are to be read before answering/commenting". Just to know if there is something else wrong as StackOverFlow suggest for posting your answers, to make it better.

As I Repeat, just answers.

Comment: Man, you know what you did

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
<link href="./Border-Color.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Using `./` at the beginning of the path means "start in the same directory as the referencing file", the "referencing file" in this case being your HTML.

As noted by others in the comments before, even though this will make sure the css file is **included** properly, since you only apply `width` and `color` of your border, and not `style`, *you still won't see any visual changes*. You need to set it explicitly, overriding the default value (which is `border-style: none`):

```
border-style: solid;
```

Answer (score -3):

There may be incorrect path in your css code. Check your path. 
or
Use absolute path(starts from https:// or c:// whatever depends on where you kept the files)

sample code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Clearly, this is not the issue. You could infer that from the already posted comments